# Как найти куратора в программировании?

Tags: работа

Интересно, а можно ли найти себе куратора в программировании, например, за "печеньки" или бесплатно делать работу для накопления опыта? Меня интересует есть ли такие ресурсы или только фриланс и там уже писать по заказу?

p.s. Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос немного не сюда, просто не знал куда написать)

Comment: Это глупость, забудьте об этом, а то потратите и время и деньги.

Comment: @shatal вообще-то я такую штуку начинаю где-нибудь летом. Возьму себе пару человек - правда, далеко не новичков - и буду их подтягивать, а заодно и себя по тем местам, где что-то пропустил. Сейчас не начинаю, потому что и без того веду бесплатные курсы, но совсем для новичков. И вообще http://phpmentoring.org/

Comment: Уточните предметную область которая вас интересует (web, mobile, desktop..) и предпочитаемый язык программирования.

Comment: @anber меня интересует web - языки программирования javascript, python. Начинал учиться программировать на C, Java.

Comment: @Etki: сложно что-либо сказать, так как это похвально, но мне, как видимо и автору, хотелось бы большего. Я не первый год учусь, но не гений, знания даются с трудом, а ещё больше время уходит на выявление проблемы. Поэтому хочется не просто участвовать в разработке супер-про, а чтобы он тебе все разжевал, а ты его после этого бросил и забыл. Но на такое никто не согласится, а на обратное не соглашусь я и такие же желающие быстро войти в тему. Ну а в итоге я хочу того, что нереально, вот и советую забить на все это.

Answer (score 6):

Проблема в том, что брать ученика, даже если он будет хотеть выполнить какую-либо работу просто ради опыта, бесплатно никто не станет. Почему? Потому что объяснить задание (что и как нужно сделать) будет намного дольше и сложнее, чем сделать эту же работу самому. Я даже не понимаю откуда такой миф. Часто встречаю в соцсетях начинающих программистов с предложениями "возьмите меня бесплатно, буду делать вашу работу ради опыта"... чтобы поручить кому-то свою работу, надо: 1) доверять этому человеку. 2) знать, что он справится. В других случаях придется много времени тратить на описание задания, а потом еще часами всё перепроверять. Это очень тяжело.

Answer (score 3):

Лучший способ научиться плавать - залезть в воду.

Базовые знания можно приобрести по книгам-самоучителям и в веб-самоучителях. А затем начинай что-то делать, что-нибудь, что кажется важным/выгодным/нужным и т.д. Это и будет боевой опыт и боевое обучение. В процессе иногда будешь сталкиваться с абсолютными тупиками (для самого себя), но всегда есть возможность задать вопрос на профильном форуме или здесь и получить ответ.

Говорю на основании собственного опыта. Есть ли другой вариант? Нет. Насколько мне известно, учиться можно либо самому, либо на курсах, но после этого все равно что-то нужно начать делать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего никак. Но если подумать, то вопрос фантастически актуален. Тот, кому удастся институционализировать кураторство в программировании, совершит в рамках программирования революцию, равноценную Эпохе Просвещения в рамках всей культуры. Ведь ощутимый эффект просвещение дало не тогда, когда отдельные мастера типа Леонардо стали брать себе учеников для помощи в выполнении своей обычной работы, а тогда, когда появились университеты. То есть появились специальные обособленные места, куда можно было придти исключительно для обучения под чутким руководством опытного наставника.

Не знаю, как аналогичное место может выглядеть в современном мире и применительно к программированию. Возможно, это должен быть сайт, на котором можно записаться в группу к какому-то наставнику, а затем получать от него учебные задачи и дельные советы по тому, как их следует решать. Ясно одно. Это должен быть не сайт быстрых вопросов и ответов, а скорее сайт для вступления ученика в очень долгосрочные отношения с наставником. И ещё отдельный вопрос. Как заманить на такой сайт наставников? Допустим, что возможность поделиться своим опытом и так уже достаточно мотивирует. Но как этот сайт будет обеспечивать наставникам такую отдачу, которая бы позволяла им уделять своей деятельности достаточно времени и сил? Тот, кому удастся придумать работающий способ, определённо впишет своё имя в историю...

Comment: Так уже институализировали и совершили революцию: https://www.udacity.com/nanodegree

Comment: @Nofate Это совсем не то. По формату очень похоже, но нужного эффекта никогда не даст из-за того, что участие для учеников платное. Образование может иметь массовый эффект только тогда, когда оно бесплатное.

Comment: Кураторы тоже кушать хотят.

Comment: @Nofate Это понятно. Их никто за это не упрекает. Просто это не будет иметь такого же эффекта, как бесплатные универы.

Comment: Мне кажется, не взлетит. Программирование перестало быть искусством, и стало ремеслом, коммерческим занятием. Здесь не может быть никакого «беззаветного служения». Поэтому и распространённого института учеников не получится. Но всё же плюс за веру в человечество!

Comment: Интересные мысли. Но я бы сместил акцент, добавив 3 слова в  последнее предложение: Тот, кому удастся придумать **работающий способ** ***сделать человека умнее***, определённо впишет своё имя в историю...

Comment: @VladD Я думаю, что в той части, в которой программирование является ремеслом, ему можно научиться без куратора. По книжке "Изучаем фреймворк X за 21 день".

Comment: @avp В такой расширенной формулировке вопрос уже решён. Университеты уже делают людей умнее. И некто Вильгельм фон Гумбольдт уже надёжно вписал себя в историю, придумав этот формат. Хорошо бы сделать нечто подобное в более узком формате - чисто про программирование. И чтобы учиться не 5-6 лет фулл-тайм, а как-нибудь попроще.

Comment: @Shamov: Я знаю только один хороший текст в стиле «Изучи X за Y»: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: Мне кажется, вы всё же недооцениваете сложность программирования как ремесла. Чтобы стать хорошим ремесленником-программистом, недостаточно прочитать книги, написанные ремесленниками-авторами.

Comment: @VladD Конечно, мало просто прочитать книги опытных ремесленников. Нужно ещё набить собственную руку. Но это можно сделать без какого-либо внешнего руководства.

Comment: @VladD Не отрицая правильности указанного текста, я всё-таки хочу отметить, что Питер Норвиг известен своей эпатажностью. Принимая на работу в Гугл Кена Томпсона и Гвидо Ван Россума, он проверял их на знание Си и Питона, соответственно, точно так же, как и любых других кандидатов.

Comment: @Shamov: Эпатажность — это привычка говорить вслух то, что все знают, но боятся сказать? Я, кстати, поддерживаю Норвига:  «написал язык» не значит «умеешь программировать на нём».

Comment: @VladD Гораздо более существенным аспектом эпатажа является то, что это провокационная выходка. Я не думаю, что Томпсон и Гвидо просто "написали языки". Всё-таки они ещё немного на них программировали. Думаю, мотивация Питера была совершенно иной, нежели простая проверка навыков. Если бы Александреску или Степанов пришли к нему на собеседование, то их он скорее всего тоже проверил бы на понимание шаблонов и знание STL-контейнеров.

Comment: @Shamov: Я не вижу провокации. Наоборот, никто не должен доверять чужому мнению о том, что «ну вот этот дядька-то точно знает X». И если так, то ничего странного нет в том, чтобы быть последовательным в этом.

Comment: @VladD Это очень странно. Потому что я вижу только провокацию. Это исключительно эстетический жест. В нём нет ничего рационального. Можно было спокойно пропустить формальный тест на знание языков и тупо сэкономить время. Уверен, никого бы это не возмутило.

Comment: @Shamov: Я вижу в этом внутреннюю консистентность, согласие с самим собой. Правило «я проверяю знание C++ у **всех**» выглядит гораздо лучше, чем «я проверяю знание C++ у всех, кроме Страуструпа», «всех, кроме Страуструпа и Александреску», «всех, кроме людей в списке, см. Приложение 1». Рациональности здесь нету, но следовать принципам нерационально, да. (Рациональность вообще обычно предполагает экономию на качестве.)

Comment: @VladD Ладно, принимается. Учитывая, что интеллект устроен принципиально нерациональным образом, человек, написавший огромную книгу об искусственном интеллекте, может себе позволить быть слегка нерациональным.

Answer (score 0):

гугли "форумы вебмастеров" и там пиши "привет ребята, я нуб, возьмусь бесплатно за любую работу". 3-4 месяца тебя по задачам покидают. сэкономишь 3-4 года на курсах.

придется тяжело и будешь гуглить по 12 часов в сутки. зато потом станешь "матёрым".